# asp.net how render html input radio to postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using the code below to create radio buttons dynamically to a webpage as each set of data is retrieved from a database by iteration. It works well. The only problem is I need these to PostBack so further data can be retrieved depending on which radio button is clicked. I tried doing this with RadioButton controls but these wouldn't position inside of a table cell like the `<span>` technique does and they wouldn't create through a `<span>`.

```
int count = 0;                
            if (dataReader.HasRows)
            {                    
                testLabel1.Text = "dataReader.HasRows: " + dataReader.HasRows;                  
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    count += 1;  

        htmlString.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                    htmlString.Append("<tr>");
                    htmlString.Append("<td>");                            

                    htmlString.Append(dataReader["dateTime"] + "<br />" + "<span><input type='radio' id='rd1'/>SOMTEXT </span>" + dataReader["statistics"]");
        htmlString.Append("</td>");
                    htmlString.Append("</tr>");
                    htmlString.Append("</table>");
                    htmlString.Append("<br />");
                }                
                test_populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
                dataReader.Close();
                dataReader.Dispose();
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding `runat="server"` in `<span><input type='radio' id='rd1'runat='server'/>SOMTEXT </span>` but it didn't create the radio button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first, I encourage you to to use a declarative style to display data, bind to datasource, you can read about DataRepeater here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx
If you want to get postback from radiobutton, you need attribute **AutoPostBack** set to true (the same about CheckBox)
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' AutoPostBack ="true"  />

Comment: @vitalygolub: Thanks, this is useful information for me both with the reference and the AutoPostBack. I've never dealt with DataRepeater but I am keen to use it. The issue I have with the RadioButton is that I am unable to insert these programatically into a table cell unless I add these as <span><input type='radio' id='rd1'/>SOMTEXT </span>. Even when I place it under <<<htmlString.Append("<td>")>>> the buttons are created at the top most left corner of the page before the table where the htmlString is displayed. The text code you've shown doesn't work in my htmlString.

Comment: @vitalygolub: I am looking for a way (if any) to render a HTML radio button to PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, how to format code in comment. One more again - if you write runat="Server"  in your hand-made html, it does nothing, because this code will not be compiled, you just write html answer manually. On the other hand compilation of declarative language (asp.net, razor or any other) makes javascript, you can do it manually too, but B.Gates kindly agreed to do it for you :-)

Asp.Net design

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table border ="1">
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td style="width:200px">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" 
                      />
              </td>
              <td  style="width:200px" >
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="false" Text = '<%# Eval("Text") %>' AutoPostBack ="true"  />
              </td>
          </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# CodeBehind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int num = 10;
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i < this.Repeater1.Controls.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    RadioButton r = (RadioButton)this.Repeater1.Controls[i].Controls[3];
                    if (r.Checked)
                    {
                        num=int.Parse(r.Text.Substring(0, r.Text.IndexOf(' ')));
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            this.Repeater1.DataSource = GetAll(num);
            this.Repeater1.DataBind();

        }

        DataTable GetAll(int count)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
            DateTime bs = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int value = r.Next(3, 10);
                dt.Rows.Add(value.ToString() + " rows will be shown");
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Method GetAll() returns table, having count lines. In each line is text "%i rows will be shown" with random number. Table is bind to data repeater on page load event. If it is postback, number of rows is parsed from text of radiobutton inside repeater row (you can't get it from data table, it is another page, data table is already in GC)